# Translation csv file in magento theme directory

Tags: magento2, tax, localisation, vat, i18n

-v 2.3
theme - luma
locale - UK

I need to change '**excl tax**' to '**excl vat**' on my `catalog/cart` pages and believe I need to create a CSV file with the translation contained this file.

My question is that the doc pages say to have this file in `app/design/frontend/{themepackage}/{themename}` in my system I have `app/design/frontend/Magento` the Magento directory is empty.

The theme directory I have is in path `vendor/magento`. 
So where do I save the CSV file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it inside `app/design/frontend/Magento/{luma/blank}/en_US/i18n/your_csv_file.csv`

If Magento directory is empty create the `{luma or blank}` and the rest of the folder.
Then run **`upgrade`** command and redeploy static files.

Comment: I'm reading documentation saying that the path to 'my_csv_file.csv' should be app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/i18n the path you say has a en_US directory